# Flip animation in Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my app, I need to make an animation i.e, by clicking a button a Transparent Messagebox or a Grid should flip from bottom containing buttons. Can anyone suggest an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an animation in `Expression Blend` and call `animation_name.Begin()` in button's `Click` event handler